# Qt, enums and metaobject compiler

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qgadget

I have a following user class:

```
class MyLine : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_ENUMS(Base::LineState)

public:
    explicit MyLine (QWidget *parent = 0);
};
```

Also I have base class containing all global enums:

```
class Base
{
    Q_GADGET

    Q_ENUMS(LineState)

public:
    // The states for MyLine
    enum LineState
    {
        Empty, Correct, Wrong
    };
};
```

When I compiled this code I got a following error: `undefined reference to "Base::staticMetaObject"`

What need to do?

Comment: Do you mean `Q_ENUMS(LineState)`?

Comment: Where's the declaration of Base? Note that enums used with Q_ENUMS must be declared in a QObject subclass.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not help me. In documentation writed: `Use Q_GADGET instead of Q_OBJECT to enable the meta object system's support for enums in a class that is not a QObject subclass`. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html

Comment: Sorry, I mistaken in the name of class (I just renamed some variables when posting code for clearity) :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need first `Q_ENUMS(Base::LineState)` in `MyLine` class, you are generating this meta data in `Base` class.

Also you have to add header file with `Base` class to list of `HEADERS` in pro file so the moc tool could generate code for meta data.

Comment: `You don't need first Q_ENUMS(Base::LineState) in MyLine class, you are generating this meta data in Base class` - it is genius and it work! I deleted this part of code and all are working now. Thank you for help!